# How to stream Android Phone Screen to the PC

Tags: android, screen, screen-capture, transmission

How to stream the currently displayed screen from my Android device to the PC in real-time? Are there paid/free tools available to do this?

Comment: Unclosed duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31472962/use-adb-screenrecord-command-to-mirror-android-screen-to-pc-via-usb

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was searching for the same thing, and this showed up: MyMobiler, http://mymobiler.com/?p=42.

As I write this I'm installing it, so I haven't tried it yet.
Hope this works for you, ;-).

(source: http://www.smartphonegurus.com/forums/topic/6044-question-how-to-view-mobile-screen-from-pc/)

Comment: Another tool is Webkey (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.webkey&hl=en). It's for free and works through the browser but requires root privileges. Yet another tool is https://code.google.com/p/androidscreencast/. Both suffer from low refresh rates (4-5 fps).

Comment: I used to use MyMobiler all the time for my Windows Mobile devices. I wish I could say the android version was as good. Still it is the best I have used so far. It is also great for using your computer's mouse and keyboard on the android devices.

Comment: Vysor is really good, almost no installation needed https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vysor-beta/gidgenkbbabolejbgbpnhbimgjbffefm/related