# compress adb screencap on python

Tags: python, adb, screenshot

Yes, I can get the png stream from the shell

```
adb exec-out screencap -p
```

python code like this

```
start_time = time()

pipe = subprocess.Popen("adb exec-out screencap -p", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
img_bytes = pipe.stdout.read()
read_time = time()

img = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(img_bytes, np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
end_time = time()

print('stream size', len(img_bytes))
print('read cost', read_time - start_time)
print('decode cost', end_time - read_time)
print('screencap cost', end_time - start_time)
```

Yet it is still too slow

```
size 2452217
read cost 2.630615234375
decode cost 0.0625
screencap cost 2.693115234375
```

Can I compress the screencap before output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your device supports it, try using:

```
adb exec-out screenrecord --output-format=h264 -
```

This will instead output a h264 movie stream, which will be compressed significantly less demanding on both the adb host and mobile device.

For more information, check out [Use adb screenrecord command to mirror Android screen to PC via USB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31472962/use-adb-screenrecord-command-to-mirror-android-screen-to-pc-via-usb/39538161)

Additionally, there are multiple arguments you can specify as well:

```
--help  Displays command syntax and options
--size WidthxHeight     Sets the video size: 1280x720. The default value is the device's native display resolution (if supported), 1280x720 if not. For best results, use a size supported by your device's Advanced Video Coding (AVC) encoder.
--bit-rate rate     Sets the video bit rate for the video, in megabits per second. The default value is 4Mbps.
--time-limit time   Sets the maximum recording time, in seconds. The default and maximum value is 180 (3 minutes).
--rotate    Rotates the output 90 degrees. This feature is experimental.
--verbose   Displays log information on the command-line screen. If you do not set this option, the utility does not display any information while running.
```

Source: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#screenrecord

Comment: Thanks, but video is slower than screenshot

Comment: What device are you using and how are you connecting via ADB, Wi-Fi or USB?

Comment: Emulator. Now I found the best way: use uiautomator2, only need 0.2s

Comment: @molysama im looking for same solution how u were able to take screenshot using uiautomator2 please share some resources.