# Mirroring an android device to an android tv box with ADB

Tags: android, adb, screen, mirroring

I have a certain video streaming app for android that detects if the device is connected to another screen, either through HDMI or some Wifi-mirroring app, and won't let you play videos if you do so.
The solution I came up with is to use adb and [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) or [the screenrecord  command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31472962/use-adb-screenrecord-command-to-mirror-android-screen-to-pc-via-usb) alternatively, which are not detected by the streaming app.
This works very well on my PC, but since there is no computer in the bedroom I need a machine there to do the same mirroring as well.

The machine I have available is an android tv box - [X88 max plus](https://www.aliexpress.com/i/32891903065.html).

I managed to use this box as an adb host for my smartphone - but not farther from there.
Like expected I can't simply pipe the video from the adb screenrecord command to an android media player.
The following command works on the adb side, but an empty player opens or not at all:

```
adb exec-out screenrecord --bit-rate=16m --output-format=h264 --size 1920x1080 - | - am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW  -t video/mp4
```

I did extensivley try to install armbian linux on it, but it seems like the bootloader won't run it (This specific box is not very common and I couldn't find anyone who managed to install armbian on it).

My question to you is if there is actually a way to make this video piping work in the android OS or if you can think of a way to port scrcpy to android easily.

Thanks in advance!